# Backing up with rsync, how not to get into trouble with permissions and privileges?

Tags: hard-drive, backup, permission

I am backing up files to an external hard drive using rsync as a test, usually I just copy pasted but I read that rsync is more reliable and does a checksum to verify the copy so I am trying it out now.

I'm just using it as: `rsync -a --progress [SOURCE] [DESTINATION]`

I noticed in the manual page relating to rsync that it also copies the permissions and privileges, in fact after the copy when I right click and "*get info*" on the files and folders, they have the same "*Sharing and Permissions*".

When I check files backed up during previous backup processes (using copy/paste), sometimes the permissions are *"read & write"* for the current user (me) and *"no access"* for everyone else, some have *"read only"* for everyone and spotlight.

**My question is:** how can I be sure that the backed up files and folders will at least be **readable by future users on my external hard drive**. In other words, **when I'll access the hard drive using a fresh clean install of my OS using a new/fresh/possibly-new-with-a-different-user-name-account**, how can I be sure that I won't be locked out of my files by permissions etc ? I would like to at least get read only. 
Do I have to manually right click every file and folder then *"get info"*  and go to "*Sharing and Permissions*" and then choosing *"Read & Write"* for everyone ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

1. You can always access the files by being an admin on the computer you attached the external drive to and changing them. The admin super-user can always fix permissions issues.
2. You can change permissions at the top level by clicking "Apply to Enclosed Items" That will change everything in the folder and below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

External hard drives typically mount with the option `noowners`. The entire volume is set to ignore permission. The `Get Info` window will show that you are the owner and the group will show as your primary group (usually `staff`).

Comment: Thanks for your input, indeed I tried to access files using another user account the Mac, and I could still access and edit them while they were on the drive, the main user had switched to the current user in *"Sharing and Permissions"* in *"Get Info"*.